# Error solving: $\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=3+2\cos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

I've the simple following trigonometric equation to solve:
$$
\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=3+2\cos(x)\,.
$$
There are some different ways to solve this, but one way is giving me a different answer and it's intriguing me because I don't see the flaw in the argument. If I use the fact that:
$$
\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=\pm \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}}
$$
and then I take the square of both sides of the trigonometric equation, I get:
$$
\frac{1-\cos(x)}{2}=\left[3+2\cos(x)\right]^2\,,
$$
which can be solved by sostitution. If I do so, I get the solution:
$$
x=\pi+2\pi k, \,where \,\,k\in\mathcal{Z}\,,
$$
but the actual solution of the initial trigonometric equation is (it can be obtained using other methods as previously stated):
$$
x=\pi+4\pi k, \,where \,\,k\in\mathcal{Z}\,.
$$
So, where is the problem? I think it's some hidden condition of existence that I'm not taking into account, but I do not see where. I get it that, since initially I've $\sin(x/2)$, the final solution should be $4\pi k$ periodic, but from using the half angle formula it does not show up apparently. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think I see it... When I use the half angle formula, I have to take $\sin(x/2)>0$ since the second hand size of the trigonometric equation is positive. From this inequality I've that: $4\pi k<x<2\pi+4\pi k$, with $k\in\mathcal{Z}$. This reduces the solutions from the one that I was getting, to the correct ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $x=3\pi/2$. The equation becomes $-1=1$. This equality will be correct, if you square both sides. But it is incorrect as it is.

When you square both sides, it can happen that you acquire false roots.

The right side is always positive. So you must add the condition $\sin(x/2)>0$ for your squaring both sides to be correct.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my own comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Instead of squaring and getting extraneous solutions, rewrite $3 + 2 \cos x$ in terms of a double angle formula for $\cos x$, i.e. $$\cos x = 1 - 2 \sin^2 \dfrac {x}{2}$$  Once you do a little simplification on the right hand side, you should have a quadratic in $\sin \dfrac {x}{2}$, which is easily factorable.  One side will have no solution, while the other will look almost the same as what you came up with, but the answer will come immediately once you take $\sin \dfrac {x}{2}$ into account.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides the solution obtained $x=\pi+2\pi k$ generates spurious solutions and contains also the correct solution $x=\pi+4\pi k$.